# Using MySQL triggers to clone entries in a table after insert or edit

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, edit

I know its possible to clone an entry from one table into another table using MySQL triggers and I would like to make this operation for both insert and edit actions. For insert action I managed to find a way, but I can't seem to make it work for edit.

To put it simple, my tables look something like this:

**The main table**

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| lead_id, title, owner_id, description, date_added |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

**The audit table**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| audit_id, lead_id, title, owner_id, description, date_added, date_modified |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If lets say I want to edit the entry with `lead_id = '4'` from the main table, how can I get that id in the trigger in order to save the modified entry in the audit table with `lead_id = '4'`?

Comment: So you want to update the record in the audit table or add a new entry while updating the main table ?

Comment: I want to add a new record after updating the main table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the insert you can log the data into `audit` as

```
delimiter //
create trigger audit_insert after insert on main_table
for each row
begin
  insert into audit_table(lead_id,title,owner_id,description,date_added)
  values
  (new.lead_id,new.title,new.owner_id,new.description,now());
end ; //
delimiter ;
```

For the update you can have the following trigger

```
delimiter //
create trigger audit_update after update on main_table
for each row 
begin
  insert into audit_table(lead_id,title,owner_id,description,date_added,date_modified)
  values
  (new.lead_id,new.title,new.owner_id,new.description,old.date_added,now());
end ; //

delimiter ;
```

Make sure the audit table `audit_id` is auto incremented and date fields are having `datetime` datatype.